# Understanding usage of firebase in Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

The following is example code from the [official firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/bindings/angular/guide.html)

```
var app = angular.module("myChatRoom", []);
app.factory("ChatService", function() {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/chat");
  return {
    getMessages: function() {
      var messages = [];
      ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        messages.push(snapshot.val());
      });
      return messages;
    },
    addMessage: function(message) {
      ref.push(message);
    }
  }
});
app.controller("ChatCtrl", ["$scope", "ChatService",
  function($scope, service) {
    $scope.user = "Guest " + Math.round(Math.random()*101);
    $scope.messages = service.getMessages();
    $scope.addMessage = function() {
      service.addMessage({from: $scope.user, content: $scope.message});
      $scope.message = "";
    };
  }
]);
```

I would like to understand what is going on here, as I can't assuredly see why this is actually working.

`getMessages()` is called only once, when the controller fires. Nevertheless the event bindings will fire even when `getMessages()` is never called afterwards. As well, the $scope property is updated.

Why is that? Also, is that the recommended way of using firebase with an Angular service/factory?

Comment: As of the new 0.8 release, the docs have been updated with some much better examples of services. There are also some helpers for [extending factories](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/bindings/angular/guide.html#section-extending-factories)

Answer (score 2):

In `getMessages` you have the following call:

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  ...
```

This registers a callback that gets called whenever a child is added to your Firebase chat.

Even when `getMessages` exits, that callback will remain registered. So that is why you only have to call `getMessages` once. The name is a bit counter-intuitive, I would probably call it something like `registerMessageHandler` or `registerForNewMessages`.

Either way: the callback will be triggered for every added child, until you either turn it off (by calling `ref.off("child_added"`) or until the page reloads. This is known as an **asynchronous** operation: the callback will happen, regardless of where the original flow is. The flow of the callback and your main code are **asynchronous**. It is in that sense similar to a regular JavaScript `setInterval` (which also keeps firing asynchronously, while your main code continues) or a common XMLHttpRequest (which will normally fire after its calling method returns).